# How do you get a ListBoxItem from a data-bound ListBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, listboxitem

I have a ListBox bound to a collection of objects derived from UserControl. After the list has been populated, I need to occasionally update a property on my visual controls--but I don't know how to reach them. I have a reference to the ListBox, and from that I can get references to all the data items in the list, but I can't seem to get the controls bound to them.

Here's what doesn't work, despite what Microsoft's documentation says:

````
        var lbx = TheListBox;
        var items = lbx.Items;
        var count = items.Count;
        for ( int index = 0; index < count; ++index ) {
          var item = items[ index ];
          var container1 = lbx.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem( item );
          var container2 = lbx.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex( index );
          // <item> is never null, but <container1> and <container2> are always null
        }```
````

Comment: "*bound to a collection of objects derived from UserControl*" - this sounds odd. The UserControl should be in the ItemTemplate of the ListBox, and you should bind its ItemsSource to a collection of data items.

Comment: @CharlesJenkins: Are `container1` and `container2` always `null`, i.e. in all iterations? Is the `ListBox` databound by the time your `for` loop executes?

Comment: @CharlesJenkins: It should exist when you select it in the UI. Please provide a minimal [repo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @mm8, this loop is in the ListBox's SelectionChanged handler. Is it possible that even with the item in the list and being selected in the UI, the container does not yet exist? (I can't answer about subsequent iterations, because being unable to get the container here where I need it to adjust one property leads to an infinite loop and stack overflow. The property I'm trying to change is one that prevents items from triggering a Property Changed event that would otherwise cause them to be selected in the list and fire this very handler again before we're done handling it!

Comment: @CharlesJenkins: Are you sure that the event handler doesn't fire before you have actually selected an item?

Comment: @mm8, I'm not calling the handler myself, the ListBox is, so I don't think it is being called out of turn. I will have to do as you suggest and make a new project which is a minimal reproducible example.